# rsync ignoring exclude directories and backing up itself

Tags: rsync

I know that there are few tickets with similar topic already but none of them helped with my issue.

I am using rsync to backup contents of/to 2nd HD that is mounted under /media/. Of course, I would like to have /media/* excluded, otherwise it will run into the indefinite loop.

My current rsync script that lives under /etc/cron.weekly

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -rf /tmp/*
rm -rf /media/LocalBackup/backup.3
mv /media/LocalBackup/backup.2 /media/LocalBackup/backup.3
mv /media/LocalBackup/backup.1 /media/LocalBackup/backup.2
cp -al /media/LocalBackup/backup.0 /media/LocalBackup/backup.1

# Backup Entire system incrementally
rsync -aAXS --inplace --delete / --exclude={'/var/log/*', '/dev/*','/proc/*','/sys/*', '/tmp/*','/run/*','/mnt/*','/media/*','/lost+found'} /media/LocalBackup/backup.0
```

Unfortunately, despite all my efforts, contents of /media/* IS included and rsync goes into an indefinite loop of backup up itself. I am running out of ideas.

When I run script, I am also getting this error, which might be related but I don't understand its meaning as all those directories do exist:

```
rsync: change_dir "/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync: change_dir "/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*," failed: No such file or directory (2)
IO error encountered -- skipping file deletion
```

any ideas, suggestions?

**Edit:**
Changed single quotes to double quotes, but still, same issue (contents of /media/ is being backed up):

```
rsync -aAXS --inplace --delete / --exclude={"/var/log/*", "/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*", "/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} /media/LocalBackup/backup.0
```

Comment: Is it not excluding the other directories as well? Your single quotes are escaping the globs which is causing your script to attempt to exclude a directory called `/media/*` and not the subdirectories of `/media`. The same is true of the others. You need to use double quotes instead.

Comment: /dev/* is also not excluded but tmp, run, sys, proc looks empty as it should

Comment: @NasirRiley : Unfortunately that was not it :( after running the updated script, contents of /media/ is still being backed up

Comment: Doesn't rsync work relative to your working directory? If you start at the root, the exclusions should then be without the leading slashes.

Comment: `rsync` does its own interpretation of wildcards in excludes, so quoting them is not a problem. On the other hand, the spaces between some items in the list is a *huge* problem; bash will treat each space-separated item separately, so it won't even consider it for brace expansion. That is, it'll pass `rsync` the arguments "`--exclude={/var/log/*,`" (yes, the brace and comma will be literally included), followed by "`/dev/*,/proc/*,/sys/*,`", then "`/tmp/*,/run/*,/mnt/*,/media/*,/lost+found}`".

Comment: I recommend putting `set -x` before the command, so `bash` will print its interpretation of the command. One warning, though: it won't so much print what's being executed, as a command that's *equivalent to* what's being executed. There are generally many ways to quote/escape an argument that contains funny characters, and bash may not show the one you'd expect (or one that has anything to do with how you specified the argument).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think @Gordon Davisson is on to the right answer in the comments: there should be not be any spaces in your exclude list. And quotes (single or double) are unnecessary. Ref: https://askubuntu.com/questions/320458/how-to-exclude-multiple-directories-with-rsync#320459

Also:

- Exclude patterns are always **relative to your source directory**. So in general you should never use absolute paths in your exclude patterns. In your case the source directory is / so perhaps you get away with it (or not?) but it's still not a good idea.
- `--exclude` and all other options are supposed to appear **before** the source directory in the rsync command line.
- It may be easier to write and maintain your excludes if you use an `--exclude-from=FILE` option, where you list your exclude patterns, one per line, in an external FILE as described at the same AskUbuntu link above, and in the [rsync man page](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html).
- The `--dry-run` option is very handy for showing what your rsync command will do, before actually doing it. Since that typically prints many lines, you can redirect its output to a text file and open that in an editor for easier review.